# How do you integrate Pycharm with MySQL these days?

Tags: python, mysql, pycharm

So I just installed MySQL because it's part of a Python course on working with databases. The installation was fine, it confirmed I was connected, and Pycharm also installed and imported the connector with no problem.

But on the Pycharm platform, it refuses to let me connect, saying "caching_sha2_password' is not supported".

Also, NONE of the regular upper case commands will work, like SHOW DATABASES; in either Shell or on Pycharm. It acts as if they're completely unrecognized. Since a lot of the resources are from a while back, I'm not sure whether they've changed their syntax or not.

I have tried mysql_native_password, caching_sha2_password, and the personal one I used when installing, and it still says the same thing. I already changed to sql mode, and it makes no difference. What's going on? In this worth trying to fix? Thanks.

Comment: Ok guys, no need to be pissy...I pay attention when it asks me if any other questions resemble it, and it did not display any at the time.